# How to repair garage ceiling?

Tags: repair, drywall, ceiling, garage

The attic of my house is unfinished. My son accidentally fell to the filing and caused the garage ceiling broken.

Please see the images.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Can you advise me how to repair this?

Comment: Pricing and contractor questions are off topic here so I've removed that from the question. See [what topics can I ask about here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about having a completely finished appearance then you can just buy a sheet of drywall and cut it to size to fit the hole. Make the hole bigger first using a utility knife or a drywall saw so that the edges are nice and square. And make the whole process easier on yourself by making the hole a rectangle. Screw it in with coarse thread drywall screws.

Comment: I you could have any link, it would be great. I am not sure to repair from garage or ceiling.

Comment: If the hole is in the garage ceiling you may be required to use fire resistant materials.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Clean out the hole and all the broken drywall.
2. Use drywall screws and screw 2 or 3 cross pieces of strapping across the back side of the hole.
3. Then you can cut a new piece of drywall and fit it to the hole and you have something to screw it to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a How-To link that shows a lot of the basics.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQxGpcGGBk0

longneck mentioned all the process, the video will show the same, as well as some tips on taping. Also as mikes mentioned, the garage is typically done in a fire resistant (fire code) sheet rock which usually 5/8" thick, though sometimes 1/2' will be used. Check the thickness of a cut edge at the repair area or scrap that was removed.
If you do it yourself, the materials will be under $50 US, probably closer to $30
Check out some of the other drywall repair videos on Youtube, there is always more than one way to tackle the same problem.